# Generalised Eigenvalues in Python

Tags: python, eigenvalue

I am trying to solve the generalized eigenvalue problem A.c = (lam).B.c where A and B are nxn matrices and c is nx1 vector. (lam) is the eigenvalue.

I am using python. I tried something like eig(dot(inv(B),A)) from numpy.linalg but it turns out to be VERY unstable in my problem since it involves inversion. So I have been reading that it is possible to do it in MATLAB but I couldn't find any function or method to do it in python. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks...

Comment: I don't know enough about Linear Algebra anymore to conceive of a general algorithm/approach to solve that.  Could you describe the algorithm you intend on using?  If so, then I can likely give you Python code that does it. Or are you looking for a library that already does this for you?

Comment: It may be worth looking at your problem again - you hardly ever _need_ to invert a matrix, it just seems like it sometimes. http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/01/19/dont-invert-that-matrix/ Inversion, as you noted, often very numerically unstable and should be avoided (if possible!).

Answer (score 6):

Why don't you try using [scipy](http://www.scipy.org/)?  It has a method in it's linear algebra module [scipy.linalg.eig](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.eig.html#scipy.linalg.eig) that can be used to "solve an ordinary or generalized eigenvalue problem."

```
scipy.linalg.eig(a, b=None, left=False, right=True, overwrite_a=False, overwrite_b=False)[source]

    Solve an ordinary or generalized eigenvalue problem of a square matrix.

    Find eigenvalues w and right or left eigenvectors of a general matrix:

    a   vr[:,i] = w[i]        b   vr[:,i]
    a.H vl[:,i] = w[i].conj() b.H vl[:,i]

    where .H is the Hermitean conjugation.
```